# I wanna read data from my binary file after the writing process complete and also read data without the writing process

Tags: c++, file, stl, binary, 2d-vector

Here is my part of the code from binary file writing. 
here I'm passing a 2d vector table that contains text format data or binary data. if the main table contains binary data I wanna read and load that data into one vector table. I already done that if the data is text file I can load that data from that file, but it's a binary data I don't know how can I load. I am also using index table. That means that table contains size of the each field in main table.

For eg: 
emp.idx

field - Size

name - 20

age - 2

sex- 10

mainTbl - main table containing the binary data.

```
typedef vector <string> record_t;
typedef vector <record_t> table_t;
table_t mainTbl;

table_t fileStruct::FormatData(table_t &mainTbl)
{

fstream fs("emp.bin",ios::binary | ios::out | ios::in); 

size_t rowLength=mainTbl.size();
size_t colLength=idxTbl.size();
count_t  colSize;
    for (size_t j=0;j<colLength;j++)

    {
        colSize.push_back(idxTbl[j].fsize);
        //cout<<"colum size "<<colSize[j]<<endl;
    }


    for(size_t i=0;i<rowLength;i++)

    {

    for (size_t j=0;j<colLength;j++)

        {

        string data=mainTbl[i].at(j);

        data.resize(colSize.at(j),' ');

        mainTbl[i].at(j)=data;
        int len = data.length();
        fs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&len),len);
        fs.write(const_cast<char*>(data.c_str()),len);

        //cout<<data;
        //fu<<mainTbl[i].at(j);

        }
    fs<<endl;
    //cout<<endl;
    }

    return mainTbl;

 }
```

Comment: What structure is idxTbl? What is count_t? What's the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake in your writing code

```
fs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*> (&len),len);
```

should be

```
fs.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof len);
```

To read you can read into a temporary vector and create the string from that.

```
vector<char> temp;
fs.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&len), sizeof len);
if (len > 0)
{
    temp.resize(len);
    fs.read(&temp[0], len);
}
mainTbl[i].at(j) = string(temp.begin(), temp.end());
```

Comment: @ArunSelvaSuresh That's a shame, if you said *what* isn't working then maybe someone could help you.